# Expected ratio of probabilities--is there a term for it?

Tags: bayesian, information-theory, kullback-leibler

I recently came across the following quantity when I played around with some information theoretic quantities and Bayesian learning. Given three probability distributions $q(z), p(z)$ and $p(z|x)$.

$$\int_z q \log {p(z) \over p(z|x)} dz,$$

where I have sloppily introduced $q = q(z)$ as a shorthand.

**I wonder if anyone can point me to applications or interpretations of that.**

Here is what I derived myself. It is relatively straight forward to recognize this as the difference of two cross-entropies:

$$\int_z q \log {p(z) \over p(z|x)} dz = \mathbb{H}(q, p(z|x)) - \mathbb{H}(q, p(z)).$$

That is the average number of excess bits needed if $p(z|x)$ is used to encode events of $q$ instead of $p(z)$. E.g. it is a measure of how good $p(z|x)$ is at encoding events from $q$ in comparison to $p(z)$.

Comment: Yes, the expression as difference of the Kullback-Leibler divergences would have been my solution as well!